# AngularJS to Angular directive conversion

Tags: angularjs, angular

I had this directive in AngularJS now I want to convert it into Angular:

```
angular.module('mobApp.services').
    directive('googlePlaces', function(ShareObjectService){
    var googlePlaceComponents = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
        sublocality_level_2: 'long_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name',
        sublocality_level_1: 'long_name'
    };          
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level"/>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
              var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
              // console.log(place.formatted_address);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(place));
              var addressObject = {};
              addressObject['formatted_address'] = place.formatted_address;
              addressObject['lat'] = place.geometry.location.lat();
              addressObject['lng'] = place.geometry.location.lng();
              for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (googlePlaceComponents[addressType]) {
                  addressObject[addressType] = place.address_components[i][googlePlaceComponents[addressType]];
                }
              }
              ShareObjectService.setGooglePlace(addressObject);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and I was using it like:

```
<google-places location=location></google-places>
```

How can I convert this whole thing into Angular?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a component class for this. Something as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'googlePlaces',
  template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" #googlePlacesAc class="input-block-level"/>',
  providers: [ ShareObjectService ]
})
export class GooglePlacesComponent {
  constructor(private service: ShareObjectService, @Query('googlePlacesAc') inputElts:QueryList<ElementRef>) {
    this.inputElt = inputElts.first;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var googlePlaceComponents = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
        sublocality_level_2: 'long_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name',
        sublocality_level_1: 'long_name'
    };          

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.inputElt.nativeElement, {});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () =>{
              var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
              // console.log(place.formatted_address);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(place));
              var addressObject = {};
              addressObject['formatted_address'] = place.formatted_address;
              addressObject['lat'] = place.geometry.location.lat();
              addressObject['lng'] = place.geometry.location.lng();
              for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (googlePlaceComponents[addressType]) {
                  addressObject[addressType] = place.address_components[i][googlePlaceComponents[addressType]];
                }
              }
              ShareObjectService.setGooglePlace(addressObject);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ho to call this in html

Comment: You can use it like that in another component: <googlePlaces></googlePlaces>.

Comment: can you please share the service file which you mentioned in above code